# Macro VBA (excel 2010) - Display system time with running seconds in user form

Tags: vba, excel

Please show me on how to display system time with running seconds in userform - vba excel 2010

Just like visual basic timer object - but I cant find any like this in macro

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

you can do this as below (found on [Ozgrid.Com Forums](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=79927)) :

in a UserForm with a label called **Label1** put the below code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Label1 = Time
    Application.OnTime Time + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Live_time"
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Application.OnTime Time + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Live_time", , False
End Sub
```

in a Public module, put this code:

```
Sub Live_time()
    Application.OnTime Time + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Live_time"
    UserForm1.Label1 = Time
    UserForm1.Repaint
End Sub
```

then run the form with the label on it.

Comment: I'd stick with this solution as it looks the simplest. But I don't believe you need to additionally run the onTime event in the UserForm. Just calling Live_time() should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you could also write this code
Application.OnTime Time + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Live_time"
UserForm1.Label1 = Time
on the initialize event of the userform.